# Should i pray sunnah before or after the Fard Prayer?

Tags: salat

Should I pray the Sunnah Prayer before or after Fard  ?

For example,  in Asr Salat  , 4 rAKAT IS Fard and 4 rakat is sunnah. Should I pray the SunnaH before paring the r dad rakat or after the 4 Fard rakAt  ?

Comment: Please check the site before asking answered questions! You may find answers [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38134/13438) and elsewhere on the site. As for 'asr there's no sunnah prayer afterwards as it is makruh to pray between' asr and maghrib (especially after the time of sufra).

Comment: @Medi1SaifMedia

Answer (score -1):

Salam Alikum Brother,

For  Assuna alratibah = السنن الرواتب there are two type: (Sunnah Qabliah = before Fard) and (Sunnah Ba'daih= After Fard):

Sunnah Qabliah=before Fard:
- 2 Rakat before Fajr.
- 4 Rakat before Dhuhur. 2 + 2 = 4 Seperated

Sunnah Ba'adiah= After Fard:
- 2 Rakat After Dhuhur.
- 2 Rakat After Maghrib.
- 2 Rakat After Isha.

bring the total for alsunnah alratibah to be 12 Rakat.

- there are no Sunnah Ratibah for Asr Prayer.

now there are other sunnah prayers but they are not Ratibah = سنن رواتب. but it mentioned in the Hadith 
- من حافظ على أربع قبل الظهر وأربع بعدها حرمه الله علىى النار
- رحم الله امرأ صلى أربعًا قبل العصر 
- بين كل أذانين صلاة، بين كل أذانين صلاة، وقال في الثالثة: لمن شاء ، وقال: صلوا قبل المغرب، صلوا قبل المغرب، ثم قال: فلمن شاء

- 4 after Dhuhur.
- 4 befor Asr.
- between every two Adhan 2 Rakat, 2 Rakat before Maghrib, 2 Rakat before Isha.
  there are also many more like Dhuha prayer but all of these are not Sunnah Ratibah ,

Comment: @Medi1Saif didn't see your comments brother. I'm new to the site and trying to figure out how it works. anyway plagiarism is too far brother, it's one religion and of course the answers gonna be similar. have a good day

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. But I'd like to point at the fact that we require answers to be primarily written in your own words and quotation to be clearly marked as such and in best case including linked references.